# Java read a file and print it, from command line arguments

Tags: java, file, io

Accept command line argument for a string to open a text file and print its contents.
Text file is like a dictionary: a list of words separated by new lines.

Using other examples this is what I've tried to no success. Do not use any java collections/libraries outside these ones.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
class test{
public static void main(String[] args) {
  File file = new File(args[0]);
   try {    
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            int i = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        sc.close();
    }
   catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO. what is your question?

Comment: `int i = sc.nextInt();` not sure what this is for based on *"Text file is like a dictionary: a list of words separated by new lines."* it seems like it would cause issues

Answer (score 0):

Unless your file contains int(s), calling `sc.nextInt()` is not correct; and when it is correct, you would want to use `sc.hasNextInt()` (not `sc.hasNextLine()`). Here, you want to use `sc.nextLine()` to read each word (since there is one per line). Also, you should check that the file exists before attempting to read from it (so you can handle that condition reasonably). Finally, I would prefer [`try-with-Resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) over explicitly managing the life-cycle of your `Scanner`. Like,

```
File file = new File(args[0]);
if (!file.exists()) {
    try {
        System.err.printf("Could not find '%s'.%n", file.getCanonicalPath());
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```